# Dudas con uso de select en php

Tags: javascript, php, mysql

Buenos días a toda la comunidad quisiera que me ayudaran con un ejemplo quiero utilizar un select múltiple y guardar esos elementos en una base de datos MySQL.

Obviamente estoy usando PHP y a también quiero editar no encuentro como hacerlo alguien me puedo ayudar o orientar con un ejemplo. hasta el momento puedo hacer lo siguiente:.

```
<div>
  <label>Solicitante:</label>
  <td>
    <select name="solicitante" id="solicitante" required>
      <option value="">Seleccione</option>
      <?php
        $query = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM personal");
        while($d = mysqli_fetch_array($query)) {
            if ($d['id'] == $alm->__GET('idp')) {
                echo '<option value="'.$d['id'].'" selected>'.$d['nombre'].'</option>';
            } else {
                echo '<option value="'.$d['id'].'">'.$d['nombre'].'</option>';
            }
        }
      ?>
    </select>
  </td>
</div>
```

este es la modificacion

```html
<?php
    $conexion = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","") or die (mysqli_error());
    mysqli_select_db($conexion,"bdtrabajo") or die(mysqli_error());

    $query = mysqli_query($conexion,"SELECT * FROM tbpersonal");
    
    ?>

    <form action="grabar.php" method="post">

      <select name="idpersona[]" data-placeholder="personas" multiple="multiple">
      <?php
         while($dato=mysqli_fetch_array($query)){
      ?>
          <option value="<?php echo $dato['id']; ?>"><?php echo $dato['nombre']; ?></option>
      <?php } ?>
    </select>

    <input type="submit" name="Guardar">

    </form>
```

Comment: Tienes un select, que seguro está dentro de un `form`. El `form` tiene un action que le envía los valores registrados en todos los campos, a una URL (que puede ser el mismo PHP, a él mismo). Hay que revisar entonces cómo viaja ese $_GET o $_POST que envía el formulario y jalar de ahí lo que venga bajo el ID `solicitante`, que es lo que buscas. Ayúdate con `print_r` y `var_dump` para ver estos datos

Comment: Si el `<select>` es múltiple recuerda agregarle el atributo `multiple` al elemento. Luego investiga tal como ha dicho @Alfabravo que ocurre cuando recibes ese formulario con el `name="solicitante"` (que me huelo a array) y luego deberás cambiar el condicional de ese `if` por un `in_array()` para remarcarlos todos con `selected` si están seleccionados varios.  En cuanto a lo que hagas con ellos dentro del PHP es cosa tuya (si quieres actualizar/insertar registros en una base de datos, etc)

Comment: si pero mi duda recalca en como puedo guardar diferentes id de la tabla personal y como volver a leerlos por ello queria un pequeño ejemplo.

Comment: Haz un `print_r($_POST['solicitante']);` al principio del script que reciba ese formulario y lo veras por ti mismo... pues será un array con los ids que puedes recorrer en un bucle normal de PHP (foreach por ejemplo) y dentro del bucle haces las consultas a la tabla personal que necesites en cada ciclo

Comment: Quizas no te lo estoy diciendo bien del todo, porque no explicas que pretendes hacer despues ni que es ese `$alm->__GET('idp')`... si necesitas guardarlos todos juntos puedes usar `implode()` sobre ese POST para convertirlo a cadena de texto y guardarlo en base de datos... y cuando lo necesites lo sacas y le haces un `explode` para volver a tenerlo en un array para trabajar con el

Comment: bueno aqui una explicacion mas solida, resulta que quiero almacenar en una tabla los id de cada persona y eso lo puedo capturar con el selec normal pero al crear un select multiple puedo seleccionar varios elementos y deseo capturar cada id de esos elementos y guardarlos en mi tabla asimismo cuando deseo editar que me muestre todos esos elementos que habia seleccionado anteriormente, espero haberme dejado entender.

Comment: la variable $alm->__GET('idp') viene a ser el id de la persona pero eso solo lo uso cuando es select normal. no he trabajado con implode() podrias darme un ejemplo para asi poder orientarme te lo agradecere.

Comment: Pon un `var_dump($_GET);` y dinos cómo estás recibiendo los select múltiple para poder ayudarte, sin esa información nada podemos hacer. Puedes pulsar en [edit] para agregar el resultado del `var_dump` antes sugerido.

Comment: @DanielPacheco Si, eso es justamente lo que me parecia que querias hacer y que explicaba en mi último comentario, pero para ello debes crear "algo" que contenga esa información, como podria ser un campo de tabla de base de datos llamado "solicitantes".  Luego, para insertarlos, podrias hacer un `INSERT INTO tabla ('solicitantes') VALUES ('".implode(",", $_POST['solicitante'])."')` y eso te los insertaria pues tipo asi: `5,7,12,23` en ese campo  (eso es la idea, ojo, que no es la forma mas segura de hacerlo ni mucho menos, pero es para que me entiendas)(y eso suponiendo que el form usa POST)

Comment: Bueno si eso es lo que pretendo hacer, te mando mi ejemplo que realize. espero me puedas ayudar. me quedo ahi. las base de datos es bdtrabajo y la tabla es tbpersonal y solo tengo dos campos id y nombre